# How to return to a specific line in the code in java?

Tags: java

*example
    if (NUM4>-1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid character in your statement, please try again.");
            EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
            "return to line '#'"
        }
I need to have a way to return to a specific line of code please, not end the program with .break*

edit
Ok well here's my code so far.

```
package cormier.email.checker;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
public class CormierEmailChecker {

/*

 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner UI = new Scanner(System.in);
    String EMAIL, EMAILSPACE, EMAILCHECK1;
    int NUM1,NUM2,NUM3,NUM4,test;
    System.out.println("Please enter your E-Mail address.");
    EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
    NUM1 = EMAIL.indexOf("@");
    NUM2 = EMAIL.indexOf("#");
    NUM3 = EMAIL.indexOf("!");
    NUM4 = EMAIL.indexOf(" ");
    test = 0;
   while(test == 0){
       test=1;
    if (NUM4>-1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid character in E-Mail address, please try again.");
        EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
        NUM4 = EMAIL.indexOf(" ");
        test=0;
    }
    else if(NUM1==-1) {
        System.out.println("E-Mail address is missing an '@' symbol");
        EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
        NUM1 = EMAIL.indexOf("@");
        test=0;
    }
    else if(NUM1==0) {
        System.out.println("E-Mail shouldn't start with an '@' symbol");
        EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
        NUM1 = EMAIL.indexOf("@");
        test=0;
    }
    else if(NUM2>-1) {
        EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
        NUM2 = EMAIL.indexOf("#");
        test=0;
    }
    else if(NUM3>-1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid character in E-Mail address, please try again.");
         EMAIL = UI.nextLine();
         NUM3 = EMAIL.indexOf("!");
        test = 0;    
    }


   }

    if(EMAIL.endsWith(".ca") || EMAIL.endsWith(".com")) {

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please restart program");
    }  
}

}
```

Comment: Java does not have goto. You'll need to implement your control flow using while/for/if/methods

Comment: If you need to do this, you should probably rethink your algorithm.

Comment: You can use loop or call another method. That's the Java way to do it.

Comment: In addition to what Cruncher said, you can also try extracting the problematic portion into an extra method

Comment: with respect to the new code you posted: What's not working here?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have a way to return to a specific line of code please, not
>   end the program with .break

Unfortunately you won't get what you "need" here. Java does not have a goto statement. However, goto's are never required. For example:

```
//code
if(condition)
    goto code
```

is the same as

```
do {
    //code
} while(condition);
```

Any logic that you want is implementable with while/if/for and methods. If you post more code, we may be able to help you figure out what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method

```
public static String message(int n){
    if (n == 1) {
        return "Hello, World!";
    } else if (n == 2){
        return "Hello Planet!";
    } else if (n == 3){
        return "Hello Universe!";
    } else {
        return "Where are my Dragons?!";
    }
}

System.out.println(message(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the control flow to something like

```
boolean valid = false;
<Ask the user to enter a value>
while(!valid) 
{
    <Have the user enter a value>
    if (value is valid) 
         valid = true;
    else
         print <error message>;
}

<Use the value>
```

Comment: I'd rather use `valid=false;` I generally try to avoid double negative stuff happening in code like: `invalid=false;`.